# Pandas groupby sum, keep specific column in the resulting data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate, slice

Let's assume I have the following data set.

```
Name   Asset    Group   PN
Anton  10       Admin   124223
Brad   15       Planer  774555
Kevin  20       Admin   234987
Brad   10       Planer  774555
Peter  25       Planer  861254
Anton  10       Admin   124223
Peter  5        Planer  861254
Kevin  35       Admin   234987
David  10       AT      561256
```

Now I want to aggregate over the column name, so I do:

```
agg = df.groupby('Name', as_index=False)['Asset'].sum()
```

Works like a charm. My output looks like this:

```
Name   Asset    
Anton  20       
Brad   25       
Kevin  55       
Peter  30       
David  10
```

However, I'd like to Keep column "Group" without changing anything of this column, so that my output is going to look like this:

```
Name   Asset   Group 
Anton  20      Admin 
Brad   25      Planer 
Kevin  55      Admin 
Peter  30      Planer 
David  10      AT
```

How can I achieve the latter result?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If possible each `Name` has same group then add column to list and aggregate `sum`:

```
agg = df.groupby(['Name', 'Group'], as_index=False, sort=False)['Asset'].sum()
print (agg)
    Name   Group  Asset
0  Anton   Admin     20
1   Brad  Planer     25
2  Kevin   Admin     55
3  Peter  Planer     30
4  David      AT     10
```

Or if need to add anya another column, then need aggregate all columns, e.g. by `first` or `last`:

```
agg = (df.groupby('Name', as_index=False, sort=False)
         .agg({'Asset':'sum', 'Group':'first', 'PN':'last'}))
print (agg)
    Name  Asset   Group      PN
0  Anton     20   Admin  124223
1   Brad     25  Planer  774555
2  Kevin     55   Admin  234987
3  Peter     30  Planer  861254
4  David     10      AT  561256
```